# Why am I getting undefined in this function?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem where the babysitter earns different rates depending on times:

The babysitter 
- starts no earlier than 5:00PM
- leaves no later than 4:00AM
- gets paid $12/hour from start-time to bedtime
- gets paid $8/hour from bedtime to midnight
- gets paid $16/hour from midnight to end of job
- gets paid for full hours (no fractional hours)

I'm wondering why I'm getting undefined when I pass through times in this function?

```
 function calculatePay (startTime, bedTime, endTime){

      function formatTime(time){
        if (time.indexOf('00') === -1){
          time = Number(time.split(":").shift()) + 1;
        } else {
          time = Number(time.split(":").shift());
        }
        if (time < 5) {
          time = time + 12;
        }
        return time;
      };

      var start = formatTime(startTime);
      var bedtime = formatTime(bedTime);
      var end = formatTime(endTime);

      var scheduleRange = {
        start: 5,
        lateNight: 12,
        end: 16,
      }

      var payrate = {
        beforeBed: 12,
        sleeping: 8,
        afterMidnight: 16
      }

      var calculateBeforeBed = function (start, bedtime) {
          if (bedtime > start && bedtime <= scheduleRange.lateNight){
          var beforeBedEarned = (bedtime - start) * payrate.beforeBed;
          return beforeBedEarned;
        } else if (bedtime > scheduleRange.lateNight) {
          var beforeBedEarned = (scheduleRange.lateNight - start) * payrate.beforeBed;
          return beforeBedEarned;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      };

      var calculateAfterBed = function (start, bedtime, end) {
        if (bedtime > start && bedtime <= scheduleRange.lateNight && bedtime <= end) {
          var afterBedEarned = (scheduleRange.lateNight - bedtime) * payrate.sleeping;
          return afterBedEarned;
        } else if (bedtime <= start && end <= scheduleRange.lateNight){
          afterBedEarned = (end - start) * payrate.sleeping;
          return afterBedEarned;
        } else if (bedtime <= start && end > scheduleRange.lateNight){
          afterBedEarned = (scheduleRange.lateNight - start) * payrate.sleeping;
          return afterBedEarned;
        }
        else {
          return 0;
        }
      };

      var calculateAfterMidnight = function (start, end) {
        if (end > scheduleRange.lateNight && start <= scheduleRange.lateNight) {
          var lateNightEarned = (end - scheduleRange.lateNight) * payrate.afterMidnight;
          return lateNightEarned;
        } else if (end > scheduleRange.lateNight && start > scheduleRange.lateNight) {
          lateNightEarned = (end - start) * payrate.afterMidnight;
          return lateNightEarned;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      };

      function finalInvoice (start, bedtime, end){
        if(start >= scheduleRange.start && end <= scheduleRange.end){
          var pay = calculateBeforeBed(start, bedtime) + calculateAfterBed(start, bedtime, end)+ calculateAfterMidnight(start, end);
          return pay;
          };
        };

    }

    calculatePay("7:00", "10:00", "1:00");
```

Comment: Because you're returning nothing. You have a bunch of nested functions that have their own `return` statements, but this has no impact on the outer function.

Comment: Which function are you getting the error for?

Comment: Seems like your `finalInvoice` function really shouldn't be a function at all. Just take the code from it, and unwrap it from `function finalInvoice(start, bedtime, end) {...}` and it should work, since you already have `start, bedtime, end` defined as variables.

Comment: If you wanted to keep `finalInvoice` as a function, then add this to the end of the outer function `return finalInvoice(start, bedtime, end);` Now you're invoking it, passing the variables as function parameters, and returning whatever it returns.

Answer (score 1):

because your function **has no `return` statement**

```js
function voidsum(a, b, c) {
  var result = a + b + c;
}

function sum(a, b, c) {
  var result = a + b + c;
  
  return result;
}

console.log('voidfn', voidsum(123, 321, 231));
console.log('sum', sum(123, 321, 231));
```